# Sum a range that contains a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a column that has a formula,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2; "."; " ")
```

In the column there is a bunch of numbers and all dots between a number are moved and replaced with space. for example if the number i 1.000.000,5 it is instead showed as 1 000 000,5. But when I want to sum that range I get 0, and I guess it is because of the formula i use. Is there a possible way to go round this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Both those numbers will be treated as text by Excel due the spaces, or two decimal points within the number.

As an example you could use this array formula:  `{=SUM(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B4:B5," ","")))}` to remove the spaces and convert it to a number - 1 00000 05 & 1 00000 06 will return 20000011.

or you could put the VALUE(SUBSTITUTE... bit in a separate column and then add it up that way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the dot "." is the thousand separator and the comma "," is the decimal point. If this format is not your localized number format then you can use the `SUBSTITUTE()` formula to correct them. After correcting them, then use the `VALUE()` formula to convert the text value into number value.

Btw, if you wish to use blank space " " as the thousand separator for easy reading, don't use the `SUBSTITUTE()` formula to create it. Instead properly convert your data into number value first (as described above), then use the number format tool under HOME tab to create your desired format.

In this way, you will be able to do summation properly.